# Unknown Column in 'IN/ALL/ANY' subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I've got 2 tables: members and member_logs.

Members can belong to groups, which are in the members table.  Given a date range and a group I'm trying to figure out how to get the 10 days with the highest number of successful logins.  What I have so far is a massive nest of subquery terror.

```
SELECT count(member_id) AS `num_users`,
DATE_FORMAT(`login_date`,'%Y-%m-%d') AS `reg_date` 
FROM member_logs 
WHERE `login_success` = 1 
and `reg_date` IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(`login_date`,'%Y-%m-%d') AS `reg_date` 
     FROM member_logs 
     WHERE `login_success` = 1 
     and (DATE_FORMAT(`login_date`,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2012-02-25' and '2014-03-04'))
and `member_id` IN 
    (SELECT `member_id` 
     FROM members 
     WHERE `group_id` = 'XXXXXXX' 
     and `deleted` = 0) 
ORDER BY `num_users` desc 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

As far as I understand what is happening is that the WHERE clause is evaluating before the subqueries generate, and that I also should be using joins.  If anyone can help me out or point me in the right direction that would be incredible.

EDIT: Limit was wrong, fixed it

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: @Strawberry What mistakes am I making with my current structure, and how could this be done with joins?

Comment: The first part of that is too boring to bother with. For the second part, consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first subquery is totally unnecessary because you can filter by dates directly in the current table member_logs. I also prefer a JOIN for the second subquery. Then what you are missing is grouping by date (day).

A query like the following one (not tested) will do the job you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(ml.member_id) AS `num_users`, 
  DATE_FORMAT(`login_date`,'%Y-%m-%d') AS `reg_date` 
FROM member_logs ml
INNER JOIN members m ON ml.member_id = m.member_id
WHERE `login_success` = 1 
  AND DATE_FORMAT(`login_date`,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2012-02-25' AND '2014-03-04'
  AND `group_id` = 'XXXXXXX' 
  AND `deleted` = 0 
GROUP BY `reg_date`
ORDER BY `num_users` desc 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! +1 for not testing the code and letting me tinker

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(member_id) AS `num_users`,
DATE_FORMAT(`login_date`,'%Y-%m-%d') AS `reg_date` 
FROM member_logs 
WHERE `login_success` = 1 
and `login_date` IN 
    (SELECT `login_date` 
     FROM member_logs 
     WHERE `login_success` = 1 
     and (DATE_FORMAT(`login_date`,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2012-02-25' and '2014-03-04'))
and `member_id` IN 
    (SELECT `member_id` 
     FROM members 
     WHERE `group_id` = 'XXXXXXX' 
     and `deleted` = 0) 
Group by `login_date`
ORDER BY `num_users` desc 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Answer (score 0):

As a slightly more index friendly version of the previous answers;

To make the query index friendly, you shouldn't do per row calculations in the search conditions. This query removes the per row calculation of the string format date in the `WHERE`, so it should be faster if there are many rows to eliminate by date range;

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) num_users, DATE(login_date) reg_date
FROM member_logs JOIN members ON member_logs.member_id = members.member_id
WHERE login_success = 1 AND group_id = 'XXX' AND deleted = 0 
  AND login_date >= '2012-02-25' 
  AND login_date < DATE_ADD('2014-03-04', INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY DATE(login_date)
ORDER BY num_users DESC 
LIMIT 10
```